# "The Grid Search" on HackerRank with R language

Tags: regex, r, substr

I've been working on a [pretty simple problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-grid-search) on HackerRank for a few days, but I'm stuck with timeout problems and I can't optimize my code any further.

The problem is this:
Given a 2D array of digits (dimensions R * C), try to find the occurrence of a given 2D pattern of digits (dimensions r * c).

Here you are a reproducible example of variables:

```
pattern <- c("11111", "11111", "11110")
text <- c("111111111111111", 
"111111111111111", 
"111111011111111", 
"111111111111111", 
"111111111111111")
R <- 5
C <- 15
r <- 3
c <- 5
```

It's sort of a regex problem, but in 2D, and this is something that I couldn't find anywhere as a ready-to-use function in R.
There are a few corner cases that I've been able to cope with, trying to avoid the brute force option (the above version is one of those cases, where the usual 'regexp' miserably fails to find the pattern).

Below it's my code: it works perfectly fine for 13 out of 15 cases, but it fails for reason of timeout when it goes against some tests with (e.g.) R*C = 500*500 and r*c = 236*208.

```
    RW <- c()
    pattern2 <- paste0(pattern, collapse = "")
    RW <- c(rep(NA,(C-c+1)*(R-r+1)))
    for (v in 1:(C-c+1))
    {
        for (y in 1:(R-r+1))
        {
        RW[(C-c+1)*(y-1)+v] <- paste0(substr(text[y:(y+r-1)],v,c+v-1),collapse="")
        }
    }
    per <- ifelse(pattern %in% RW, result <- "YES",result <- "NO")
    cat(result, "\n")
```

Please note that there are up to 5 cases for each test, and this is the reason why my code fails: while it could work breaking the test in 5 parts, it passes the time threshold when the cases are combined together with big R*C and r*c dimensions.

Does anybody have an idea on how to improve the code performance?

Comment: Indenting your `for` loops is one improvement.

Comment: Removed the indentation because SO apparently doesn't like code with more than 4 space of indentation. Now, have you got anything about the performance of my code? :)

Comment: At a glance, growing your result by one element at a time is a classic "performance killer" in R: `RW[length(RW)+1] <- [...]`. You should initialize `RW` to the correct length before hand. Unrelated to performance, naming a variable `ifelse` is just not a good move.

Comment: thanks, the 'ifelse' variable was a copy-paste error. Indeed, I used the RW indexing in that way because I was pretty lazy to use anything else. Now I changed it but it's still not enough...

Comment: I guess you are referring to [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/master/challenges/the-grid-search) challenge? If yes I suggest you include the link in your question.

Comment: @AEF thanks, I've seen another thread about HR where someone asked quite rudely the poster not to resort to external link for the problem explanation. I include it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your approach my first suggestion would be to convert the strings to numeric matrices because `substr` is probably not very fast.

You can further make use of more sophisticated matching algorithms which shift the position for more than one place like the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).

However, `for` loops will always be quite slow in R, so I feel that the best approach in this situation would indeed be a regular expression. If you concatenate the rows of the big grid into one long string the number of characters between the rows of the pattern is fixed. This means you can do something like this (which, I believe, solves the test case you gave):

```
grepl(
    paste0(pattern[1], ".{", C - c, ",}",
           pattern[2], ".{", C - c, "}",
           pattern[3]),
    paste0(text, collapse = "")
    )
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: this is pretty wonderful and indeed it uses the power of regex as I wasn't able to implement. I had thought about it, but I didn't even try to use my idea, as I wanted to keep going on my way. Nonetheless, I now have to find a way to index the pattern elements to be pasted together... but thanks, I'll try and let you know!

Comment: I've just discovered that `grepl` has an important limitation that prevents me to use it in my cases: when `C - c` values are over 255 the function throws out an error. This is what I found in the R help: _Long regular expressions may or may not be accepted: the POSIX standard only requires up to 256 bytes._ I think that I've to find another way, but I'm stucked again: the KMP algorithm seems (at first glance) to be even slower in my 500*500 text with a 236*208 pattern ...

Comment: In this case you could search (e.g. with grep) for each pattern row in each grid row. This way you get (a hopefully small number of) "candidate rows" which you can then check by brute-force.

Comment: This is a way I've tried before writing on SO, and it's more complicated. Good news is I've found a workaround: it seems that on HR I can call `stringr::str_locate`, and the new version is working again on those 13 cases. Now HR says I've a runtime error on cases 4 and 5, but no timeout. I'm investigating.